# ASP NET MVC Core 2 with entity framework saving primery key Id to column that isnt a relationship column

Tags: foreign-keys, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Please look at this case:
[image]

```
    if (product.ProductId == 0)
    {
        product.CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        product.EditDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

        context.Products.Add(product);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(product.ProductValueProduct)) { SaveProductValueProduct(product); }
    }
        context.SaveChanges();
```

When I debug code the ProductId is negative, but afer save the ProductId is corect in database (I know this is normal), but when I want to use it here: `SaveProductValueProduct(product)` after add to `context.Products.Add(product);` ProductId behaves strangely. (I'm creating `List` inside `SaveProductValueProduct`)

```
    List<ProductValueProductHelper> pvpListToSave = new List<ProductValueProductHelper>();
    foreach (var item in dProductValueToSave)
    {
        ProductValueProductHelper pvp = new ProductValueProductHelper();
        pvp.ProductId = (item.Value.HasValue ? item.Value : product.ProductId).GetValueOrDefault();
        pvp.ValueId = Convert.ToInt32(item.Key.Remove(item.Key.IndexOf(",")));
        pvp.ParentProductId = (item.Value.HasValue ? product.ProductId : item.Value);
        pvpListToSave.Add(pvp);
    }
```

I want to use ProductId for relationship. Depends on logic I have to save ProductId at ProductId column OR ProductId at ParentProductId column.

[image]

The ProductId 45 save corent at ProductId column (3rd row - this is a relationship), ***BUT*** not at ParentProductId (2nd row - this is just null able int column for app logic), although while debug I pass the same negative value from `product.ProductId` there.

**QUESTION:**
how can I pass correct ProductId to column that it isn't a relationship column

Answer (score 0):

I just use `SaveProductValueProduct(product)` after `SaveChanges` (used `SaveChanges` twice)

```
    if (product.ProductId == 0)
    {
        product.CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        product.EditDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        context.Products.Add(product);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();

    if (product.ProductId != 0)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(product.ProductValueProduct)) { SaveProductValueProduct(product); }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I set this as an answer because it fixes the matter, ***but I am very curious if there is any other way to solve this problem***. I dont like to use `context.SaveChanges();` one after another.